# How to route kubernetes nginx-ingress to dashboard in another namespace

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am trying out kubernetes and I have deployed my Nginx in the default namespace and I am trying to create a virtual server to route the dashboard.

nginx: default namespace
dashboard: kubernetes-dashboard namespace

However, when I try to create the virtual server, it is giving me a warning that the virtualserverroute doesn't exist or invalid? From what I understand, if I will want to route to a different namespace I could do so by putting the namespace in front of the service.

nginx-ingress-dashboard.yaml

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  host: k8.test.com
  tls:
    secret: nginx-tls-secret
    # basedOn: scheme
    redirect:
      enable: true
      code: 301
  upstreams:
  - name: kubernetes-dashboard
    service: kubernetes-dashboard
    port: 8443
  routes:
  - path: /
    route: kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard
```

kubernetes-dashboard

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

Any hints what I have done wrongly?  Thanks in advance.

```
192.168.254.9 - - [27/Apr/2021:07:14:43 +0000] "GET /api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ HTTP/2.0" 400 48 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36" "-"2021/04/27 07:14:43 [error] 137#137: *106 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.254.9, server: k8.test.com, request: "GET /api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://192.168.253.130:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/", host: "k8.test.com"
192.168.254.9 - - [27/Apr/2021:07:14:43 +0000] "GET /api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ HTTP/2.0" 400 48 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36" "-" 2021/04/27 07:14:43 [error] 137#137: *106 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.254.9, server: k8.test.com, request: "GET /api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://192.168.253.130:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/", host: "k8.test.com"
```

secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
type: Opaque

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-csrf
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
type: Opaque
data:
  csrf: ""

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
type: Opaque
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining a route, you need to go with an `action.pass`, as you want to redirect the requests to the service directly.

Additionally, I don't have much experience of the `VirtualServer` resource, but `Ingress` resources should usually be on the same namespace of the service that you want to serve. The Ingress Controller picks them up even if they are in a different namespace. (This means that the tls secret needs to be in that namespace tho)

So, I would put an `action.pass` and also put the `VirtualServer` in the same namespace of the resource you want to serve, something like the following:

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  host: k8.test.com
  tls:
    secret: nginx-tls-secret
    # basedOn: scheme
    redirect:
      enable: true
      code: 301
  upstreams:
  - name: kubernetes-dashboard
    service: kubernetes-dashboard
    port: 443
  routes:
  - path: /
    action:
      pass: kubernetes-dashboard
```

If you use route, then you need to define a VirtualServerRoute with that name, like explained in the documentation ( https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/#virtualserverroute-specification )

Comment: hmmm, not too sure if I get you correctly.. "Ingress resources should usually be on the same namespace of the service that you want to serve".. If I only want 1 ingress controller to serve for all namespace will this work?

Comment: From my experience, it works. We use it like that, but with Ingress definitions, not the new VirtualServer definitions yet. It could be different now, maybe the correct way would be to declare a VirtualServer in the same namespace of the Controller, then VirtualServerRoute definitions on the other namespaces so that you can refer to them like you did in your example

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it works for my testing app but when I use it for the k8 dashboard it prompted me 502 bad gateway. :(

Comment: Sorry, I copy-paste your definition but now I notice that you are using the wrong port. 8443 is the targetPort of the service, you need to use the port. Each port redirects the traffic to the associated targetPort. I've fixed my answer, try with port 443 in the upstream!

Comment: thanks for your help and spotting the port, my bad. but weirdly it's giving me error 404 now. I added the logs from the pod at the post.

Comment: Uhm, all the requests give you a 404, or only some of them? Like, from the browser the dashboard open or not? Or only the API calls gives you 404?

Comment: i am trying to setup the kubernetes dashboard to run behind the nginx-ingress. i realize that it is due to the header not too sure if you encounter or setup the dashboard before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281374/accessing-kubernetes-dashboard